# Range query for a semigroup operator (union)

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking to implement an algorithm, which is given an array of integers and a list of ranges (intervals) in that array, returns the number of distinct elements in each interval. That is, given the array A and a range [i,j] returns the size of the set {A[i],A[i+1],...,A[j]}.

Obviously, the naive approach (iterate from i to j and count ignoring duplicates) is too slow. Range-Sum seems inapplicable, since A U B - B isn't always equal to B.

I've looked up Range Queries in Wikipedia, and it hints that Yao (in '82) showed an algorithm that does this for semigroup operators (which union seems to be) with linear preprocessing time and space and almost constant query time. The article, unfortunately, is not available freely.

Edit: it appears this exact problem is available at http://www.spoj.com/problems/DQUERY/

Comment: Since you are interested in implementing an algorithm, tell us something about your data and your constraints. What do you know about your input? How big is the size of the array? Do you expect queries to share endpoints frequently? Do you need exact answers or the answer can be approximated?

Do you need any explicit performance guarantees for time and/or space?

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/800070.802185 is a link to the Yao paper, which is now hosted by the ACM and can be found through Google Scholar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's rather simple algorithm which uses O(N log N) time and space for preprocessing and O(log N) time per query. At first, create a persistent segment tree for answering range sum query(initially, it should contain zeroes at all the positions). Then iterate through all the elements of the given array and store the latest position of each number. At each iteration create a new version of the persistent segment tree putting 1 to the latest position of each element(at each iteration the position of only one element can be updated, so only one position's value in segment tree changes so update can be done in O(log N)). To answer a query (l, r) You just need to find sum on (l, r) segment for the version of the tree which was created when iterating through the r's element of the initial array. 
Hope this algorithm is fast enough.
Upd. There's a little mistake in my explanation: at each step, at most two positions' values in the segment tree might change(because it's necessary to put 0 to a previous latest position of a number if it's updated). However, it doesn't change the complexity.

Comment: We can't duplicate the segment tree N times, as that requires N^2 time (and space). Maybe it can be done by updating the same segment tree as we go and at iteration r, answer all the queries (l,r). Have to think about it some more.

Comment: We do not need to duplicate tree because it's not an ordinary segment tree. It's a persistent segment tree which can change one element in O(log N) time and space.

Comment: Could you point me to an explanation of what a persistent segment tree is? The version I know can also change an element in O(logN), but once it's changed, the old version of it is gone, and you can't query it anymore.

Comment: Found this (http://www.spoj.com/problems/DQUERY/) which is exactly my problem, while searching for a description of a persistent segment tree. Not sure why Google didn't point me to that earlier.

Comment: After some pondering, I think I can do it with the version of a segment tree I'm familiar with, although I would still appreciate it if you pointed me to a description of a persistent one.

Comment: any links for persistent segment trees?

Answer (score 0):

You can answer any of your queries in **constant time** by performing a **quadratic-time precomputation**:

```
For every i from 0 to n-1
    S <- new empty set backed by hashtable;
    C <- 0;
    For every j from i to n-1
        If A[j] does not belong to S, increment C and add A[j] to S.
        Stock C as the answer for the query associated to interval i..j.
```

This algorithm takes quadratic time since for each interval we perform a bounded number of operations, each one taking constant time (note that the set S is backed by a hashtable), and there's a quadratic number of intervals.

If you don't have additional information about the queries (total number of queries, distribution of intervals), you cannot do essentially better, since the total number of intervals is already quadratic.

You can trade off the quadratic precomputation by `n` linear on-the-fly computations: after receiving a query of the form A[i..j], precompute (in `O(n)` time) the answer for all intervals `A[i..k]`, `k>=i`. This will guarantee that the amortized complexity will remain quadratic, and you will not be forced to perform the complete quadratic precomputation at the beginning.

Note that the obvious algorithm (the one you call obvious in the statement) is cubic, since you scan every interval completely.

Comment: The obvious algorithm is for each query [i,j], iterate from i to j and count the number of distinct element in A. Since there are at most N iterations for each query, the complexity of such an algorithm is O(N*Q), where Q is the number of queries. You are correct that it's potentially cubic in N, as there are on the order of N^2 possible queries. Nobody said that there are indeed N^2 queries though...

Comment: No, you didn't give additional information on the number of different queries, and that's why I gave the alternative, on-the-fly precomputation algorithm. It also has O(N*Q) complexity, but it has much better amortized complexity than the obvious algorithm. It fits better the situation when you don't expect an important fraction of the queries to be performed.

Comment: Either way, I need a solution faster than N*Q.

Comment: OK, but you need to tell in what sense you want this: worst case, average case, amortized complexity, or some other notion you give. This is important, since we are working at the limits where time/space/exactness tradeoffs are unavoidable. And welcome to Stack Overflow!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which might be quite closely related to the segment tree. Think of the elements of the array as leaves of a full binary tree. If there are 2^n elements in the array there are n levels of that full tree. At each internal node of the tree store the union of the points that lie in the leaves beneath it. Each number in the array needs to appear once in each level (less if there are duplicates). So the cost in space is a factor of log n.

Consider a range A..B of length K. You can work out the union of points in this range by forming the union of sets associated with leaves and nodes, picking nodes as high up the tree as possible, as long as the subtree beneath those nodes is entirely contained in the range. If you step along the range picking subtrees that are as big as possible you will find that the size of the subtrees first increases and then decreases, and the number of subtrees required grows only with the logarithm of the size of the range - at the beginning if you could only take a subtree of size 2^k it will end on a boundary divisible by 2^(k+1) and you will have the chance of a subtree of size at least 2^(k+1) as the next step if your range is big enough.

So the number of semigroup operations required to answer a query is O(log n) - but note that the semigroup operations may be expensive as you may be forming the union of two large sets.

Comment: That was one of the solutions I thought of myself, but as you mention,  constructing the union of two sets (such that you can obtain its size) is linear in their sizes. I think the complexity of a query still ends up linear in j-i.